# ngModel data binding for input gives undefined in ionic

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to save the values of the user's input in the HTML input tag to a variable so i can use it to perform some functions. However, when I try to use ngModel to do data binding I get undefined for the variable I put the value in. The code is below:

> HTML

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row justify-content-center>

      <ion-col >
        <ion-img id="luxeticLogo" src ="../../assets/luxeticLogo.JPG"> </ion-img>
        <div padding>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input autocorrect="on" autofocus="on" clearInput="true" clearOnEdit="true" color="primary" inputmode="text" placeholder="Username" required="true" [(ngModel)]="userName"></ion-input>
          <ion-icon name="person" color="primary" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        </div>

        <div padding>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input autofocus="on" clearInput="true" clearOnEdit="true" color="primary" inputmode="text" type = "password" placeholder="Password" required="true" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon  name="lock-closed-outline" color="primary" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
    
        <div padding >
          <ion-button id="loginButton" size="large"  expand="block" (click)="loginSubmit()">Login</ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

> TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from  "@angular/router";
// import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  private userName:string;
  private password;
  constructor(private  router:  Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
  loginSubmit(){
    console.log("submit", this.userName, this.password);

  }

}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> OUTPUT:

submit undefined undefined

Comment: Have you imported FormsModule in your Module?

Comment: yes i have included that, please check the question again: included app.module.ts

Comment: are there any other errors in your console? the code looks correct as long as the HTML you provided is `'./login-page.component.html'`

Comment: there are no errors in my console.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned your password and user name to private the template can't access a private variable try assigning it to public

Comment: I tried making it public and it still gives me undefined

Comment: I am not really familiar with ionic but your ngmodel need to be inside of a form try to add form tag like in this example: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/forms/